# JQuery UI Custom modal dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'm trying to create a modal popup effect using JQuery UI 1.7.2
Basically I need a normal Error widget to pop up with the rest of the page blocked out.
We're using IE6 at work and there are no ways to upgrade.
Currently I'm trying this.

```
<div id="errorPopup" style="display: none;">
  <div class="ui-overlay">
    <div class="ui-widget-overlay"></div>
    <div class="ui-widget-shadow ui-corner-all" style="width: 302px; height: 300px; position: absolute; top: 1em; left: 1em;"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="position: absolute; left: 35em; top: 30em; padding: 10px;" class="ui-state-error ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
    <div class="ui-state-error ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" style="background: none; border: 0;">
      <p>
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin-right: 0.3em;"></span>
        <strong>Opps:</strong> That wasn't meant to happen.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please note the use of the JQuery UI classes. This doesn't work and I don't really know why. I am trying to avoid writing my own css and js to get the effect as the reason for moving to JQuery UI was for it to handle his stuff for me.

Any suggestions welcome!

Comment: What does your jQuery code look like?  What does happen that shouldn't?

Comment: You misspelled "oops" :-)  When you say it doesn't work, what exactly goes wrong?  The main IE6 thing I know that'll have problems is the translucent layer that the dialog code can interpose between (in the "z" axis) the page and the dialog.

Comment: have you considered using existing libraries for such things? I like facebox (http://famspam.com/facebox) There's also one called lightbox which is super popular.

Comment: What goes wrong is that the translucent layer doesn't appear. In Firefox the layer appears but there are some links that show up above the layer.

Answer (score 5):

I think what you trying to do immitate the dialog presention manually. I would suggest running the dialog using javascript, jQuery will do some funcky stuff to fix it for IE6.

Here is the simple version:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title" style="display:none;"></div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#dialog').dialog({ modal: true,
                bgiframe: true,
                open: function(){}
            });     
        });
</script>
```

If you want to do it manually it will be something like:

```
<div class="ui-widget-overlay" style="width: 1263px; height: 2253px; z-index: 1001;"></div>
<div style="display: block; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; z-index: 1002; outline: 0px none; height: auto; width: 330px; top: 169px; left: 463px;" class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all  ui-draggable" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ui-dialog-title-dialog"><div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix" unselectable="on" style="-moz-user-select: none;"><span class="ui-dialog-title" id="ui-dialog-title-dialog" unselectable="on" style="-moz-user-select: none;">Make an enquiry</span><a href="#" class="ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all" role="button" unselectable="on" style="-moz-user-select: none;"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick" unselectable="on" style="-moz-user-select: none;">close</span></a></div><div style="height: 242px; min-height: 117px; width: auto;" id="dialog" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content">ERROR STUFF</div>
```

As you can see it is very messy!

**Oh, and ONE MORE THING:** Make sure you include the '`jquery.bgiframe.min.js`' and '`bgiframe: true`' as it enables the dialog to function in IE6

Comment: Hi thansk for the answer. But I'm not trying to implement the dialog box as such. I want it to be modal but to just have the error ui widget dispalyed.
If I do the first thing you suggested then it creates it for me as a normal dialog.

Comment: @TAkinremi: Perhaps I didn't understand you fully. Try bgiframe if the its only not working in IE.

Answer (score 0):

I would be interested as to why the jQuery UI doesn't work.

You could try the following plugin. Take a look at the demos page to see if it suits
http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#

Comment: I don't really know myself but, It works almost perfectly in firefox so there must be something extra I need for it to work on IE6.